# How scan an Order with Shopify Liquid - for customised Invoice

Tags: shopify, liquid, invoice

We are producing Invoices with Shopify's 'Order Printer' app.
and want to customise the Invoice.
For instance, if they have bought a 'book' - we want it to say "Enjoy your book"
and if a 'CD' - "Enjoy the music".

I've found I can test the first item they purchased with 'limit:1' :

```
{% for line_item in unfulfilled_line_items limit:1 %} 
    productType: {{ line_item.product.type }} -   prodtype:{{product.type}} <br/>
    {% if line_item.product.type contains "cd" %}
    its a CD <br/>
    {% else %}
    it's not a CD?)<br/>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I would really like to scan the whole of the product.type array to determine how many of each product type there are - and output either/both messages - with plural 's' as appropriate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track instead of limiting though you basically want to count.

```
{% assign cd_count = 0 %}
{% assign book_count = 0 %}
{% for line_item in unfulfilled_line_items %}
    {% if line_item.product.type == "cd" %}
        {% assign cd_count = cd_count | plus: 1%}
    {% endif %}
    {% if line_item.product.type == "book" %}
        {% assign book_count = book_count | plus: 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
cd count: {{ cd_count }}
book count: {{ book_count}}
```

Now that you have a count you should be able to just do an if statement of the count numbers.

Comment: Thanks @trowse much appreciated

Comment: Small typo in above.  The line
{% for line_item in unfulfilled_lineItems %}
should be:
{% for line_item in unfulfilled_line_items %}
                                                     ^^

Comment: Even with the above change, my output is always zeros.   @trowse - do you actually have this working in OrderPrinter?

Comment: Hey @user801347 I did not try it. Just went based on my rusty liquid. There was a couple mistakes I had there... I'm not sure why increment didn't work as it is documented. See my updates above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @trowse - solved the zeros issues, they were due to OrderPrinter cache problems and limitations.  Just in case anyone needs it.  Here's our solution:

```
<!--  count how many of each product type we are/have????? fullfilling -->
        {% assign count_cd = 0 %}
        {% assign count_bk = 0 %}
        {% for line_item in unfulfilled_line_items %}
            {% if line_item.product.type contains "cd" %}
                {% assign count_cd = count_cd | plus:1 %} 
            {% endif %}
            {% if line_item.product.type  contains "Book" %}
                {% assign count_bk = count_bk | plus:1 %} 
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
<!--- end of counting -->

<!-- Enjoy.. message -->
    {% if {{count_cd > 0 %}
        Enjoy the music 
        {% if {{count_bk > 0 %}
            and the {{ count_bk | pluralize: 'book', 'books' }}<br/>
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        {% if {{count_bk > 0 %}
        Enjoy the {{ count_bk | pluralize: 'book', 'books' }}<br/>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
```